# How to import Amazon json file to R?

Tags: r, json, import

File Link : http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/qa/qa_Appliances.json.gz

How to import it to R?
Please help me out.

When I'm trying the following code:

```
library(rjson)

json_file <- "C://Users//ABC//Desktop//qa_Appliances.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse = "")) : 
unexpected character "'"; expecting opening string quote (") for key value
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hm it looks like there are several problems...
So first json expects a `"` instead a `'`... And also the whole file should be an array so the each `{}` should be concatenated with a `,` and inside a `[]`.

I also tried the `jsonlite` library which directly creates a data frame...

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(
  paste('[',
        paste(gsub("'",
                   '"',
                   readLines(json_file)), 
              collapse=','),
        ']'))
```

Comment: Hello @drmariod, Thanks for the response. When I'm trying the same code, it gave me the following error `Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text. aling the end of the machine"s service life. The plate is no (right here) ------^ – Maddy`

Comment: This is because my `gsub` command replaces all singe `'` by a double... And actually also within a sentence... It created `machine"s` which actually ends the json string there... And then it can no longer parse it... Not sure how to fix the whole thing...